# print duplicates in arrayList only one time

Tags: java

i have an arrayList ( named error_dub ) i want to print the duplicates only one time here is my code

```
for(x=0 ; x<=error_dub.size()-1 ; x++){

     for(int h=x+0 ; h<=error_dub.size() ; h++){

            if(error_dub.get(x).equals(error_dub.get(h) && x!=h){

                 System.out.println(error_dub.get(x)+" is duplicated ");
              }
       }
  }
```

here the line is printed more than once so how can i printed only once ?

Comment: Consider using the enhanced for: `for(Object obj : objects)` to make your code more readable and better represent what you're doing.

Comment: can you sort the array ? that would make the answer much simpler..

Answer (score 7):

Use two sets (this assumes `X` is the class of your object):

```
// Returns a set of all duplicates in a list
public Set<X> getDuplicates(final List<X> list)
{
    final Set<X> dups = new HashSet<X>();
    final Set<X> set = new HashSet<X>();

    /*
     * Cycle through all elements in the original list. Add it to "set":
     *
     * - if the .add() method returns true, this is the first time the element is seen;
     * - if it returns false, then this is not the first time, it is a duplicate:
     *   add it to "dups".
     */
    for (final X element: list)
        if (!set.add(element))
            dups.add(element);

    return dups;
}
```

Set's `.add()` will return false if the set is *not* modified as a result of the operation, which means if the element was already there.

Copy/paste that function into your existing code and replace the snippet above with:

```
for (final X dup: getDuplicates(error_dub))
    System.out.println(dup + " is duplicated");
```

**Important note**: the `getDuplicates()` function as it is written will NOT respect element order. If order matters to you, replace `dups` with a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Comment: `set` will have the same content as `dups`, so why not just use one collection instead?

Comment: It will not. `set` will contain all unique elements in the original list, and that includes elements appearing only once. It is only if the element is already in there, ie if `set.add()` returns false, that the element is added to `dups`.

Comment: Okay, my bad, but couldn't you just use `contains()` and one collection then?

Comment: That would be another solution, sure, but the difference in cost is negligible: in all events, the `Set` implementation will have to compute the element's hash code and call `.equals()` if the hash code has already been seen.

Comment: Sure, but you'd use only one variable and less code, so it would seem more reasonable to me to do it that way around.

Comment: @AndréHoffmann: I fail to see how I would use one less variable. I still need to collect duplicates so that they be returned!

Comment: @ranatamer: some more details on why I can use `for` the way I use it: it is because both `Set` and `List` implement `Iterable`. Each and every class which implements `Iterable` can be used in what is called a "foreach loop".

Comment: @fge: Yes, you are absolutely right, I must have been thinking of something else.

Comment: @fge: "the Set implementation will have to compute the element's hash code". Why it need to compute hashcode? As per java docs of add method of HashSet "Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false."

Comment: @Parvez granted, it does not need to -- but chances are high that two elements which are not equal do not have the same hash code either. As a consequence, most implementations create hash buckets and check, before addition, or testing the presence of an element etc, whether the element's hash code may already be present in a hash bucket.

Comment: @fge: You are absolutely correct. I looked at the java doc again and HashSet is backed by HashMap and therefore it is almost necessary to override hashCode if you are using Hash backed collection.

Comment: @Parvez: well, you do need to override `hashCode()` if you override `equals()` for another reason: the contract for both of these method pretty much requires it.

Comment: @fge: Well the contract for equals says it is 'generally' necessary to override hashCode. So my understanding is if I am using storing objects in something like ArrayList, hashCode is redundant. Again this is my interpretation and could not be true. So, I would rather not emphasize on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.add()` method of set to check for duplicates. Method posted below adds list elements to  set1. If element is a duplicate (`.add()` returns true), then element is adde to `setToReturn`

```
public Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> listContainingDuplicates)
{
    final Set<Integer> setToReturn = new HashSet();
    final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet();

    for (Integer yourInt : listContainingDuplicates)
    {
        if (!set1.add(yourInt))
        {
            setToReturn.add(yourInt);
        }
    }
    return setToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ar2=new ArrayList<String>();

    ar.add("1");
    ar.add("2");
    ar.add("3");
    ar.add("4");
    ar.add("5");
    ar.add("1");
    ar.add("2");
    ar.add("1");

    for(int x=0;x<ar.size();x++)
    {
        if(!ar2.contains(ar.get(x)))
        {
             for(int y=x+1;y<ar.size()-1;y++)
            {

                  if((ar.get(y).equals(ar.get(x))))
                {
                    System.out.print("repeating "+ar.get(x));
                    ar2.add(ar.get(x));
                    break;

                }  


            } 

        } 

    }
```

you can do like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
//method to identify the duplicate elements in array list
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dup 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("enter elements");
int g;
Scanner b= new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
g=b.nextInt();   
a.add(g);
}
HashSet<Integer> c=new HashSet<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> d=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer y : a)
{
if (c.contains(y))
{
d.add(y);
}
else
c.add(y);
}
System.out.println("original elements are:"+c);
System.out.println("duplicate elements are:");
for(Integer h:d)
{
System.out.println(h);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please add description